# How to add additional JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a mobile site and the template I'm using is based off of Jquery Mobile.

In the header.php file, the template I am using is making calls to CDN javascript files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-
1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Since I'm basically pulling in the JavaScript from those URLS and it's not actually some .js file in a folder on my web server - how would I go about adding additional javascript code?  Do I add it to my header.php?  Get a special plugin that'll allow me to add additional javascript?  The template doesn't give my any option to add additional code.  So, not sure where the code would actually go...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at these search results http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=enqueue+javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically yes, you can add those lines to your header.php file just after the wp_head() function and it'll load the jQuery from a remote source, just like it was on your local machine.

If you want to do it properly, take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script which will allow you to add it through the wp_head() hook, which will check to make sure the script hasn't already been loaded.

Comment: Thank you Christopher...this is perfect. This will work for me.